# Recursion to count words and redundant words in a sentence in c++

Tags: c++, string, recursion

Hi i'm trying to count the words in a sentence that is input by the user and this is the code i've written

```
void Count_Words( )
    {
        int count=0;
            for (i = 0; inserted_text[i] != '\0';i++)
            {
                if (inserted_text[i] == ' ')
                        count++;    
            }
            cout << "Word Count: " << count + 1;
    }
```

I need to write this using recursion but i can't figure out how.

Also i need to count the redundant words in the sentence using recursion how do i do that?

I can't use mapping i need to use basic logic to do this. Is there anyway i can do this only with basic logic?

Comment: What is `inserted_text`?

Comment: What is "basic logic"? First, create a [mcve] with non-recursive solution then ask what is not clear to you about making it recursive.

Comment: *I can't use mapping i need to use basic logic to do this* -- What does that mean "to use basic logic"?  A `std::istringstream` and a simple `while` loop that increments a count is basically the entire program.

Comment: @HattedRooster inserted_text is the text entered by the user

Comment: What type is it I meant, give us a full example.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm supposed to do this using recursion not with loops. With loops it is easy but i need help with recursion

Comment: @HattedRooster It is a string  string inserted_text;

Comment: Here is the problem with this requirement of recursion -- the issue is that this is **not** a recursive problem.  To do this using recursion doesn't really fit this problem.  You have to contort the solution in some way to fit the requirement of recursion, and it isn't clear as to how much contortion would be acceptable.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Hatted Rooster (this is not a good fit for recursion). I guess it serves a teaching purpose. So here is another option.

`countWords()` returns the number of words for the given substring until its end. To calculate the words for substring `0..n`, we can calculate the words for substring `1..n` first. And if character 0 is a space, add 1 to that.

```
int countWords(const char* str)
{
    if(*str == '\0')
        return 1; // last word

    return countWords(str + 1) // how many words are in the remaining substring?
                + (*str == ' ' ? 1 : 0); // count if the beginning of the current substring is a space
}

int main()
{
    std::string input = "test test test";
    std::cout << countWords(input.c_str()); // 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really make sense to use recursion here but anyway, this would be one way to do it:

```
void Count_Words(int& i, const std::string& inserted_text, int& count)
{
    if (inserted_text[i] == '\0')
    {
        ++count; // last word
        return;
    }
    
    if (inserted_text[i] == ' ')
        ++count;

    Count_Words(++i, inserted_text, count); //recurse
}

int main()
{
    std::string input = "test test test";
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    Count_Words(i, input, count);
    std::cout << count; // 3
}
```

The thing to take away from this code is that references are a powerful tool to achieve correct recursion as seen in the function parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer stated, this is really not a problem that should be resolved using recursion.  What if there are thousands of words?  That would exhaust the stack memory at some point.

In any event, here is one way to do this recursively:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void Count_Words(std::istringstream& strm, int& count)
{
   std::string word;
   if ( strm >> word )  // if there is a word, then increment the count
   {
     ++count;
     Count_Words(strm, count);  // go to next word recursively
  }
}

int Count_Words(std::string inserted_text)
{
   // This is the setup for the recursive calls
   std::istringstream strm(inserted_text);
   int count = 0;

   // start the recursion 
   Count_Words(strm, count);
   return count;
}

int main()
{
   std::string test = "This has four words";
   std::cout << Count_Words(test);
}
```

Output:

```
4
```